# Keep trailing zeroes in regex matching formula

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a function I've written to handle calculations of percent reductions with significant digits, and I'm having a problem with keeping trailing zeroes.
The function:

```
Function RegexReduction(IValue As Double, EValue As Double) As String
    Dim TempPercent As Double
    Dim TempString As String
    Dim NumFormat As String
    Dim DecPlaces As Long
    Dim regex As Object
    Dim rxMatches As Object

    TempPercent = (1 - EValue / IValue)
    NumFormat = "0"
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Pattern = "([^1-8])*[0-8]{1}[0-9]?"
        .Global = False
    End With
    Set rxMatches = regex.Execute(CStr(TempPercent))
    If rxMatches.Count <> 0 Then
        TempString = rxMatches.Item(0)
        DecPlaces = Len(Split(TempString, ".")(1)) - 2
        If DecPlaces > 0 Then NumFormat = NumFormat & "." & String(DecPlaces, "0")
    End If
    RegexReduction = Format(TempPercent, NumFormat & "%")
End Function
```

This trims percentages to two digits after any leading zeroes or nines:

```
99.999954165%  ->  99.99954%
34.564968%     ->  35%
0.000516%      ->  0.00052%
```

The one problem I've found isn't related to the regex, but to Excel's rounding:

```
99.50%          ->  99.5%
```

Is there a solution that will save trailing zeroes that could be implemented here?

Comment: Typically, the number of decimal places to display (whether they are zeroes or not) and any symbol (currency, percentage, etc) is done with cell [Number Format Code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68)s, not RegEx.

Comment: e.g. `?format(0.999506, "0.000%")` returns `99.951%`

Comment: I would do that, but this formula is used in multiple cells and I need each cell to display as many decimal places as is significant, which varies based on the inputs. For example, 27%, 99.50%, 99.999973% may all be on the same sheet. Changing the numberformat seemed impractical since it varies based on the inputs.

Comment: No more impractical than RegEx'ing individual cells to parse a value. A UDF could be made to return a variable number of decimal places depending on an outside condition.

Comment: I couldn't come up with an easier way to find the number of significant digits other than using a regex, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You state *'This trims percentages to two digits after zeroes or nines:'* but then give `34.564968% -> 35%` as an example. I'm sorry but I cannot reconcile any repeatable pattern to your method.

Comment: It will keep looking through a number until it finds the first two digits other than 0 or 9. In that case, 3 and 4 are not zero or nine, matching the criteria, so it doesn't match any digits past that point. It then rounds to that number of digits (two). I have edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: I modified the function to use numberformat, which cleaned things up significantly. I still can't think of a way to solve this without the regex, though, and it's still showing 99.5% instead of 99.50%.

Comment: How will you format 8.99%? As 9.0%, 9.00% or 8.99%?

Comment: Now that you mention it I'm not sure that would be handled correctly. The rationale for ignoring zeroes and nines is that if you took 12/9300000, then you should have two significant digits. But zeroes aren't significant, so you don't round to 0%, you round to 0.0013%, the first non-zero digits. Similarly, 1 - (12-9300000) Should evaluate to 99.99987%, because the nines are not significant.

Comment: Please tell me what `(1 - 899/10000)` should return. `8.99%`, `9.0%`, or `9.00%`? I ask because at first the result is 0.0899, then this has 3 significant digits, so then you format to only 2 significant digits: `9.0%`, but suddenly you have no more significant digits left because of the rounding effect.

Comment: Good point @trincot - Whether or not to include trailing (forced) zeroes is something that should be clarified.

Comment: It should return 9.0%. Working with the raw decimal value, 0.0899, the first zero is not significant, but the next two digits are. That would round up to 0.090, or 9.0%. Similarly, 0.89999 should be 0.90 or 90%. It's clear that I haven't defined the problem very well: If a decimal value begins with a 0, all consecutive zeroes should be ignored, and the first digit following them is the first significant digit. Similarly, if a decimal value begins with 9, I need to ignore all consecutive 9's. Sorry, it seems that the biggest problem here is that I haven't expressed the problem well.

Comment: Ok, @TaylorOstberg, I think I understand then. Posted my answer.

Comment: Did one of the answers suit your needs? Could you leave a comment and/or accept an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a version of your function that uses `LTrim` in combination with `Replace` instead of the (costly) regular expression to calculate the value of `DecPlaces`. The calculation of `DecPlaces` has become a "one-liner".

The rest of the code is the same except for the additional call to `CDec` to avoid `CStr` from returning a scientific notation (like `1.123642E-12`) when the value is tiny.

```
Function Reduction(IValue As Double, EValue As Double) As String
    Dim TempPercent As Double
    Dim TempString As String
    Dim NumFormat As String
    Dim DecPlaces As Long
    
    TempPercent = (1 - EValue / IValue)
     ' Apply CDec so tiny numbers do not get scientific notation
    TempString = CStr(CDec(TempPercent))
    ' Count number of significant digits present by trimming away all other chars,
    ' and subtract from total length to get number of decimals to display
    DecPlaces = Len(TempString) - 2 - _
        Len(LTrim(Replace(Replace(Replace(TempString, "0"," "), "9"," "), "."," ")))
    ' Prepare format of decimals, if any
    If DecPlaces > 0 Then NumFormat = "." & String(DecPlaces, "0")
    ' Apply format
    Reduction = Format(TempPercent, "0" & NumFormat & "%")
End Function
```

It is assumed that `TempPercent` evaluates to a value between 0 and 1.

#### Comments on your code

You wrote:

> The one problem I've found isn't related to the regex, but to Excel's rounding:
>
> ```
> 99.50%          ->  99.5%
> ```

This is actually not related to Excel's rounding. In your code the following

```
DecPlaces = Len(Split(TempString, ".")(1)) - 2
```

will evaluate to `Len(Split("0.995", ".")(1)) - 2`, which is `1`, and so the format you apply is `0.0%`, explaining the output you get.

Also realise that although you have a capturing group in your regular expression, you do not actually use it. `rxMatches.Item(0)` will give you the complete matched string, not only the match with the capture group.

You apply a number format of `0%` for the case the regular expression does not yield a match. Any number that has no other digits than `0` and `9` will not match. For instance `0.099` should be displayed with format `0.000%` to give `9.900`, but the format used is `0%` as you have no `Else` block treating this case.

Finally, `CStr` can turn numbers into scientific notation, which will give wrong results as well. It seems with `CDec` this can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a UDF that attempts to 'read' the incoming raw (non-percentage) value in order to determine the number of decimal places to include.

```
Function udf_Specific_Scope(rng As Range)
    Dim i As Long, str As String

    str = rng.Value2    'raw value is 0.999506 for 99.9506%

    For i = 1 To Len(str) - 1
        If Asc(Mid(str, i, 1)) <> 48 And _
           Asc(Mid(str, i, 1)) <> 57 And _
           Asc(Mid(str, i, 1)) <> 46 Then _
            Exit For
    Next i

    If InStr(1, str, Chr(46)) < i - 1 Then
        udf_Specific_Scope = Val(Format(rng.Value2 * 100, "0." & String(i - 3, Chr(48)))) & Chr(37)
    Else
        udf_Specific_Scope = Format(rng.Value2, "0%")
    End If

End Function
```

[image: specific_scope]

The disadvantage here is removing the numerical value from the cell entry but that mirrors your original RegEx method. Ideally, something like the above could be written as a sub based on the [Application.Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property. Just highlight (aka Select) some cells, run the sub and it assigns a cell number format with the correct number of decimals to each in the selection.